# Display all records for mySQL field and count how many times they appear for specific date

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

My desired result is to display how many times each video (title) was watched for specific dates, by grabbing all of the titles that appear in the table, and count how many times that title is recorded for specific years / months.

It is working, however, it is not displaying correctly.

Instead of

TITLE A - 2 
TITLE B - 6 
TITLE C - 4
TITLE D - 0

...

It is displaying like this

TITLE A - 2
- 6
- 4
TITLE BTITLECTITLED

my code:

```
    //get report
    if ($_GET['report'] == "custom") {          //custom date report
        $month = $_GET['month'];
        $year = $_GET['year'];

            $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT title AS displaytitle 
FROM user_history GROUP by title");

        if ($_GET['month'] == "") {

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT title, COUNT(id) FROM user_history
 WHERE year(date) = '$year' GROUP BY title");

        } else {

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT title, COUNT(id) FROM user_history
 WHERE year(date) = '$year' AND month(date) = '$month' GROUP BY title");
        }


            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
            $new_title = $row2['displaytitle'];


            echo $row2['displaytitle'];


                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo ' - ' . $row['COUNT(id)'] . '<br />';
                }

    }
```

Can anyone offer a solution so that a count will display next to the title? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have a separate query retrieving the title and the counts when the title is in both tables? They're also not connected in any way, so the counts you're showing are not actually for the title you printed at all.

Comment: @Dan Grossman - Because I want for all of titles to display, but I only want to count how many for the year or month / year. Do you know a better way?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit my question to reflect that.

Comment: Goodness, please sanitize your inputs if this is at all real (even toy) code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to display the title is outside the loop. If you want the title to be printed next to every value, put it inside the loop printing every value.

```
if ($_GET['report'] == "custom") {          //custom date report

    $sql = "
    SELECT
      titles.title,
      COUNT(DISTINCT history.id) AS `count`
    FROM
      user_history titles
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
      user_history history
    ON
      titles.title = history.title
    ";

    if (!empty($_GET['month']) && !empty($_GET['year'])) {
      $sql .= "AND YEAR(history.date) = " . (int)$_GET['year'] . " AND MONTH(history.date) = " . (int)$_GET['month'];
    } else if (!empty($_GET['year'])) {
      $sql .= "AND YEAR(history.date) = " . (int)$_GET['year'];
    }

    $sql .= "
    GROUP BY 
      titles.title
    ORDER BY 
      titles.title
    ";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo $row['title'] . ' - ' . $row['count'] . '<br />';
    }

}
```

Comment: the query doesn't seem to be valid...

"Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in..."

Comment: Try to display how the query is resolved by php. Maybe it's just a problem of missing space before "and year"

Comment: Thanks, Nick! That problem was a simple typo:

ON title.title ... should have been ON titles.title

Comment: This looks better, accept it's not exactly correct. I have four test records in the table. There are three separate titles. Title A has been watched twice while Tiles B & C have each been watched once. It is displaying: <br /><br />
TITLE A - 4<br />
TITLE B - 1<br />
TITLE C - 1<br />

Comment: I added another record for TITLE C and it jumped to 4! Hm.

Comment: It's multiplying by itself ... 2 views was four...3 views is 9. I'd be willing to be that 4 views would be 16.

Comment: UPDATE: I created a new table for the video titles, and it fixed the multiplication problem, although, if you had a fix for this with one table, I'd sure like to know. Thanks!

Comment: I have made some changes, does it work right now? Don't make another table, this is possible several ways with only one table, it's just difficult as I'm writing off the top of my head. I do not have tables to try it on.